# User name before sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, user-accounts

I got a script requiring sudo, but the script must set parameters according to the original user, such as:

```
chown "${USER}:${USER}" dir
```

If I set it under sudo, I just end up with `chmod root:root`, which doesn't help.

So how can I get the user name before sudo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The environment variable SUDO_USER should work as a replacement for USER.

Since you are setting the ownership to USER:USER I assume there is always a group with the same name as the user? A more strict solution might otherwise be to use SUDO_UID and SUDO_GID.

Two possible solutions would then be:

```
chown "${SUDO_USER}:${SUDO_USER}" dir
```

or

```
chown "${SUDO_UID}:${SUDO_GID}" dir
```

Comment: Nice anwser, with the solution AND some additional infos.

Comment: Using the UID/GID is the best solution, as it is possible to have multiple UIDs with the same username.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `SUDO_USER` variable:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $SUDO_USER'
```

From the [sudo](http://www.courtesan.com/sudo/man/1.8.10/sudo.man.html#x454e5649524f4e4d454e54) man page:

> **sudo** utilizes the following environment variables. The security policy has control over the actual content of the command's environment. [...]
>
> `SUDO_UID`
>      Set to the user ID of the user who invoked sudo.
>
> `SUDO_USER`
>      Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.

Comment: But why `sudo echo $SUDO_USER` outputs nothing?

Answer (score 1):

SUDO_USER can be overwritten by the user.

```
 $ SUDO_USER='lala' sudo SUDO_USER='test' printenv | grep USER
 USER=root
 SUDO_USER=test
 USERNAME=root
```

You should use 'who am i' or 'logname' to get the original username

```
toto:~$ SUDO_USER='lala' sudo SUDO_USER='test' logname             
toto
toto:~$ SUDO_USER='lala' sudo SUDO_USER='test' who am i
toto   pts/4        Jan 23 15:13 (:0.0)
```

Coming from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands

Comment: After running 'sudo su -' the environment variables aren't available, but `logname` and `who am i` work.

Comment: You're right, it's not possible to rely on environment variable.

Comment: Found on some host that SUDO_USER can't be overwritten:

`sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: SUDO_USER`

So it may still be safe, should still verify this.

Comment: It's because my command is set as "NOPASSWD", so it depends on your sudoers configuration via "NOSETENV".